# Unwanted AJAX request sent

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send an AJAX request to login. Yesterday it was working perfectly but today when I send a request it sends one request perfectly but a second is unwanted. I'm stuck how to deal with this. Please help.

```
$('#login_form').submit(function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();

    $.post("<?php echo base_url() ?>login/login_user",
        $(this).serializeArray(),
        function(data) {
            if (data == 0) {
                $(".user").show().delay(2000).fadeOut();
            } 

            if (data == "Epass") {
                $(".pass").show().delay(2000).fadeOut();  
            } 

            if (data == "admin" || data =="other") {
                $(".success").show().delay(2000).fadeOut();

                if (data == "admin") {
                    window.location.href = "<?php echo base_url() ?>dashboard";
                } else {
                    window.location.href = "<?php echo base_url() ?>index";
                }
            };
        });
    })
```

[image: this is firebug result of ajax request]

Comment: Use console.log()  to debug.  What are you seeing?

Comment: Given the unprocessed PHP code in the JS error, it looks like your code is being called from a non-PHP page. Do you have that same code block in a .html include, or other .js page?

Answer (score 0):

Set `asynchronous` to `false`, when you need that ajax request to be completed before the browser passes to other codes

```
 $.ajax(... async: false ...);
```

Comment: ***NEVER SET ASYNC TO FALSE***. Aside from being *terrible* practice to use, it will have no effect on the outcome of the OPs problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following part of your code is causing you the 2nd call

```
if (data == "admin") {
    window.location.href = "<?php echo base_url() ?>dashboard";
} else {
    window.location.href = "<?php echo base_url() ?>index";
}
```

Try (with semi-colon ';' at the end of the PHP echo call):

```
if (data == "admin") {
    window.location.href = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>dashboard";
} else {
    window.location.href = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index";
}
```

Comment: how about you comment out the window.location.href lines, could it be the one causing the 2nd call?